# I want to insert empty rows and columns to a 2D list, using python

Tags: python, printing, 2d

I have a 2 dimensional list, size 9x9. I want to add empty rows after third and sixth row, and empty column, after third and sixth column.
How can I do that?
I figured out, that for rows, I can use list.insert(3, " "), but I can't manage to add an empty columns.
Please help me!

```
000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000

000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000

000 000 000
000 000 000
000 000 000
```

That's how it is supposed to look, when printed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help!

Here is my solution, I made it!!!!

```
list = sudoku[:]

for row in list:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] == 0:
            row[i] = "_"

i = 0   
while i < 9:
    x = 0
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print()
    while x < 9:
        print(f"{list[i][x]} {list[i][x+1]} {list[i][x+2]}  ",end="")
        x += 3
    print()
    i += 1
```

Sudoku is supposed to be a 2d array filled with zeros: e.g. sudoku[[000000000][000000000]... and so on]

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a 2 dimensional list (filled with zeros), size 12x3 with :

```py
my_list = [[0 for j in range(3)] for i in range(12)]

# my_list is now:
"""
[
    [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]
]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is to manipulate an array, and that is best served by the `numpy` module. Here is an example of inserting a line and a column using `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np
example = np.ones((9, 9)) 
# you can use np.array(your_list) in order to use custom values
# Here, it will be full of 1

# insert a line of 0 at index 3
example = np.insert(example, 3, np.zeros(9), axis=0)
# Note that we insert a line of size 9

# insert a column of 0 at index 3
example = np.insert(example, 3, np.zeros(10), axis=1)
# Note that we must insert a column of size 10 since we added a line previously
```

If you want to return to using lists of lists after having inserted your columns and lines, you can use: `example.tolist()`

Here is a link to the numpy documentation of `np.insert`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html